# Sharing database between android native code and phonegap code

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite, phonegap-plugins

I have an app which consists of a common database accessed from native code and phonegap code of the same app, however, I am not able to access data written into the db by the native code in the phonegap code. I am using following code snippet for android -

`public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {`

```
public DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, "dbName", null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void addNotification(String data) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    values.put("data", data);
    db.insert("myTable", null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

but when I try to accces the data from "myTable", I dont get any data and the table is empty, I have checked the ddms to ensure that data is populaated in the table, I am using the sqlite plugin for phonegap on android (https://github.com/pgsqlite/PG-SQLitePlugin-Android)

I have this doubt that could it be possible that native and phonegap parts are somehow using the different database and not the common database.

Answer (score 0):

If you read code from https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-legacy-build-support/tree/master/src/android/io/sqlc. The plugin code does not use SQLiteOpenHelper class to create sqlite database. The plugin is using another method SQLiteOpenFlags to create of database table. I have same problem like you also.